# Why do we take `(Bias) ^2` in total error in a model?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, variance, bias, overfitting

I was recently studying some book and few blogs and come to note that :

`Total error  = Bias^2 +Variance + irreducible error`

Also, I know that these are the errors but I have problem understanding, How do we quantify these errors?  What I mean by this is : Give few data points and the predicted and the true value. How do we measure Bias, variance and irreducible error?

Comment: @Xi'an How is it related to pythagoras theorem ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the blogs or a reference to the book?

Comment: 1) from dimensional analysis alone it is clear that bias must be squared ... 2) search this site for error decomposition (or bias-variance decomposition) must be answered before.